# What is different about Python class dictionaries?

Tags: python, oop, class, dictionary

I was having trouble with class properties in Python 2.7, managed to find a solution, but I don't understand it.

In the following contrived code, I expect each Song to have its own dictionary, containing lyrics of the days of the week mentioned.

```
class Song:
  name = ""
  artist = ""
  # If I comment this line and uncomment the one in the constructor, it works right
  week = {}
  def set_monday( self, lyric ):
    self.week[ "Monday" ] = lyric;

  .
  . # silly, I know
  .

  def set_friday( self, lyric ):
    self.week[ "Friday" ] = lyric;

  def show_week( self ):
    print self.week

  def __init__(self, name, artist):
    self.name = name
    self.artist = artist

    # Uncomment the line below to fix this
    # self.week = {}

def main():
  songs = {}

  friday_im_in_love = Song( "Friday I'm in Love", "the Cure" )
  friday_im_in_love.set_monday( "Monday you can fall apart" )
  friday_im_in_love.set_tuesday( "Tuesday can break my heart" )
  friday_im_in_love.set_wednesday( "Wednesday can break my heart" )
  friday_im_in_love.set_thursday( "Thursday doesn't even start" )
  friday_im_in_love.set_friday( "Friday I'm in love" )
  songs[ "Friday I'm in Love" ] = friday_im_in_love

  manic_monday = Song( "Manic Monday", "the Bangles" )
  manic_monday.set_monday( "Just another manic Monday" )
  songs[ "Manic Monday" ] = manic_monday

  for song in songs:
    # This shows the correct name and artist
    print songs[song].name + " by " + songs[song].artist
    # The dictionary is incorrect, though.
    songs[song].show_week()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Except that when the above code is run, the output looks like this:

```
Manic Monday by the Bangles
{'Friday': "Friday I'm in love", 'Tuesday': 'Tuesday can break my heart', 'Thursday': "Thursday doesn't even start", 'Wednesday': 'Wednesday can break my heart', 'Monday': 'Just   another manic Monday'}
Friday I'm in Love by the Cure
{'Friday': "Friday I'm in love", 'Tuesday': 'Tuesday can break my heart', 'Thursday': "Thursday doesn't even start", 'Wednesday': 'Wednesday can break my heart', 'Monday': 'Just another manic Monday'}
```

Neither dictionary looks the way I expect it to. So going back to the code, if I comment `week = {}` up top, and uncomment `self.week={}` in the constructor, the dictionaries come out the way I expect.

```
Manic Monday by the Bangles
{'Monday': 'Just another manic Monday'}
Friday I'm in Love by the Cure
{'Friday': "Friday I'm in love", 'Tuesday': 'Tuesday can break my heart', 'Thursday': "Thursday doesn't even start", 'Wednesday': 'Wednesday can break my heart', 'Monday': 'Monday you can fall apart'}
```

**Why is this?**

I realize the `name = ""` and `artist = ""` lines are (probably) unnecessary but since they *do* work, I must ask: Since the name and artist string properties appear to work fine "initialized" outside the constructor; why doesn't the week dictionary?

Comment: Nothing wrong with "silly" examples (although if you really want to embrace the culture, you should try using ones based off of the better-known Monty Python sketches - that's standard). You do seem to have some lingering semicolon-itis, though.

Comment: Hey Mike, this is Adam Forsyth from NU, we worked together at Norris your last year. How's life? (I know this isn't a social site, but I couldn't help saying hello.)

Comment: I'll admit to the semicolon-itis readily - I still spend most of my time in PHP (and I'm picking up Javascript). Duly noted about the Monty Python - I'll try to remember that next time :) Thanks again, Karl. And hey, Adam! Long time no see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I realize the name = "" and artist = "" lines are (probably) unnecessary but since they do work, I must ask: Since the name and artist string properties appear to work fine "initialized" outside the constructor; why doesn't the week dictionary?

The code works *exactly because* they are unnecessary. However, the *lines* don't "work fine" because they *don't 'work' at all* because they are irrelevant because they are unnecessary.

If you set up the week dictionary in `__init__` it will work even if you leave the `week = {}` line in the class, because the same mechanism will kick in.

Let's look at this a little more closely:

```
# If I comment this line and uncomment the one in the constructor, it works right
week = {}
```

Python follows a very simple rule: things that are written inside the `class` block belong to the class, not to individual objects. To attach something to an object named `self`, you assign to one of its `self.attributes`. In this regard, `__init__` is not special; it may be automatically called and have a specific purpose, but it otherwise interacts with objects the same way as any other method. (Hence the need for a `self` parameter even in `__init__`.)

In your `__init__`, you do:

```
self.name = name
self.artist = artist
```

This attaches an attribute to each object of the class (since every object gets `__init__` called) that **hides** the one in the class. When attributes are **looked up**, they are looked up in the class as well as the object (if they can't be found in the object), but when they are **assigned**, they are simply assigned to the thing that you say to assign it to. (To modify a `Song` attribute, you would use `Song.whatever = 42`, even inside a method.)

**The problem occurs when you create an attribute in the class and also don't ever assign an attribute to the instances.** Note that, again, `__init__` is not special; you can create new attributes of the class later.

Now, since `__init__` is not special, let's say we do the work of one of the sample functions inside `__init__`:

```
self.week["Friday"] = "gotta get down"
```

Do you see the difference? `week["Friday"]` is not an attribute name; `week` is. So we *cannot create a new attribute like this*. Instead, we are **modifying** the **existing** object that is looked up as `self.week`. Which finds the one in the class, because the object doesn't have one. And when we look up `self.week` again, we will see that change, even if `self` is a different `Song`, because there is only one `Song.week`.

*If we replaced `self.name = name` with something that modifies the existing object, then we would see the same behaviour*. However, we **can't** actually do that: the initial value of `self.name` is `''`, which is a string, and Python strings provide *no way to modify them in-place*. When you re-assign to a variable that holds a string, you do exactly that: re-assign. You cause the variable to stop being a name for the old object, and start being a name for the new object. Since we can only affect `self.name` by assignment, we can't affect `Song.name` unless we explicitly refer to `Song.name`.

The simple solution is to set up the attribute in `__init__`:

```
self.week = {}
```

Comment: ````things that are written inside the class block belong to the class, not to individual objects.```` This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. The rest is just icing on the cake. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually C and Java and C# and all the others that are strange in this regard, because there, data described inside the `class` statement belongs to objects (in the sense that memory is allocated for them per-object), but the methods (member functions in C++ parlance) do not (as that would be a ridiculous and useless waste of resources). This is because those languages see the class merely as a description of some objects (although you can explicitly invoke "reflection" in Java and C#), but Python sees it as *itself an object in its own right*. Just like functions and even *modules*. :)

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable; you cannot mutate them, only *rebind* them.

Dictionaries are mutable; they can be changed, and *everyone can see the changes*.

Create them by assigning to the attributes of `self` within `__init__()` instead.